# How are milestones ordered in GitHub?

Tags: github

How are GitHub milestones ordered? Is it possible to order them somehow?

They're not ordered alphabetically (I tried adding 0, 1, 2, etc., didn't work).

They're not ordered by last update.

UPDATE: I usually create several milestones without due date. How are those ordered?

Comment: Are they ordered due date then alphabetically?

Answer (score 2):

They are ordered by due date. Items with no due date are put at the top of the list.